# Popup window with recycler view background not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-popupwindow

I want to show popup window with Recycler view for menu.

popup window top right corner -> i am showing sort up arrow icon.

So i set the transparent background for popup window and showing recycler view with white background.

```
`menu.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));`


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvCategory"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_bg"/>
```

elevation is not working for recycler view. Its not looking like menu without border and elevation.
[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avj8g.jpg)

Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired look you can modify your popup view xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="6dp">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvCategory"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in the code where you initialize your popup it should be like this(here mContext is your Activity):

```
PopupWindow mPopup = new PopupWindow(mContext);
View popUpView = mContext.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_popup_xml, null);
// other initializations
mPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
mPopup.setContentView(popUpView);
mPopup.setFocusable(true);
mPopup.setClippingEnabled(true);
```